# Google Analytics Easy Tracker Memory Issues

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am trying to integrate Google Analytics in my Activities. As per the official documentation i used the "Easy Tracker" Library provided by Google and extended my activities from "TrackedActivity" The exact syntax i use is:

```
EasyTracker.getTracker().trackPageView("/myview"+viewname);
```

I am getting Null Pointer Exception randomly but Logcat shows "at Google Analytics" and surprisingly not at any place in my code. In some of my activities, I am calling system.gc() function in the onDestroy() method. (Could be the issue) Its supposed to be a singleton object I am worried if its getting garbage collected?

Needless to say as of now my app crashes. What worries me further is that even if i do a try catch or put exception checkers ie. check across null object. I am still worried that my activities might not get tracked even if the Crash is avoided.

Please Suggest.

Comment: Maybe you should take a look at this bug. http://code.google.com/p/analytics-issues/issues/detail?id=139&q=android&colspec=ID%20Component%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Stars%20Summary You're possibly experiencing it. I think there's a good chance it's being erroneously affected by the GC. So you could add that info here.

Comment: `system.gc()` is called from 3/10 activities. And it sometimes crashes without even going in those activities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you don't invoke methods of `EasyTracker` before `onStart()` of your Activity. Also  set `ga_debug` and `ga_auto_activity_tracking` to `"true"` to get debug statements and to track all activities of the application respectively.

Comment: `ga_auto_activity_tracking` is used to enable app tracking. I am more interested in tracking individual pages. So i am using trackPageView API provided in the library